# Find URLs where a specific image is being displayed - Wordpress

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, image, macos

I have an image path eg.

```
 htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/room.jpg
```

I want to find the pages (URLs) on my WordPress install where this image is being loaded.

This is a WordPress site on a LAMP server, I have a local install on my OSX machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be performance costly, but maybe you could query the database using something like this:

```
SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_content like '%uploads/2016/06/room.jpg%';
```

Take the result and parse through it with some PHP regex:

```
<?php

$file = '/uploads/2016/06/room.jpg';
$mysqlResult = []; // Your result of the sql

$numImages = 0;
foreach($mysqlResult as $content){

    preg_match_all('/'.$file.'/', $content, $matches);
    $numImages += count($matches);

}
```

This is not tested, but you should be able to do it like this. But as I said, this will affect your performance, maybe not right now, but later on, when you get a lot of posts and a lot of images to run through.

Another way could be a hook into the save method in WP and then update a database table or file with the name and amount of images you have used in that post.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue using a method similar to this.
Thanks Ulrik!